# how to handle mysql result query to send them over big query table

Tags: mysql, jdbc, google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I'm writing a Google Apps Script to send data from a Mysql Database to a Big Query table.

I know how to query a mysql data base. I know how to write data from csv file or a Google sheets into Big query. However, I'd like to be able to send the mysql query results directly to BigQuery. how can I do this?

Basically, my SQL results are stored in a variable :

`var results = stmt.executeQuery('select * from table');`

The table is pretty basic :

```
Col1        Col2     Col3
String 1    foo1     1
String 2    foo2     2
String 3    foo3     3
etc...      etc...   etc...
```

From the Big Query side script I have this:

`var data = results.getBlob().setContentType('application/octet-stream');`

obviously, when running my script I have the following error :

`Cannot find function getBlob in object`

I don't really understand how I can access my data within the `results` variable and I don't know how to format them in a readable format to execute the following `.getBlob().setContentType('application/octet-stream')`

So far I've tried to pass the `results` values in a new variable called `rawdata` with a push method using the following loop:

```
  while (results.next()) {
    var rowString = '';
    for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
      rowString += results.getString(col + 1) + '\t';
    }

    Logger.log(rowString);
    rawdata.push(rowString)
  }
```

However `rawdata.getBlob().setContentType('application/octet-stream');` return me the same error.

I have no clue how to format my rawdata or results variable.

Comment: Seams that `getBlob()` needs to be used on a (CVS) file? see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery

Comment: so I don't have any other options than using CVS as an intermediate?

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

- Attempting to get blob from string/array using `getBlob`, when no such method is available on either type.
- Using `\t` to create csv.

#### Solution:

- `csv`, by default uses comma `,` as field separator and newline `\n` as row separator
- You need to create a new blob using Utilities.

#### Snippet:

```
  var rawdata = [];
  while (results.next()) {
    var rowString = '';
    for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
      rowString += '"' + results.getString(col + 1) + '",';//quotes " if present in results data, must be replaced with double quotes ""
    }
    rawdata.push(rowString.slice(0, -1))
  }
 var data = Utilities.newBlob(rawdata.join('\n'),'application/octet-stream');
```

#### References:

- [Utilities](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#newBlob(String,String))
- [RFC4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#page-2)
- [BigQuery CSV options](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#csv-options)
- [BigQuery CSV Load snippet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery#load_csv_data)